# Laravel request validation using pivot table

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, pivot-table

I have a model `Paper`. Paper can have different sizes and colors but sizes only relate to some colors and so on. I have a pivot table set up where sizes correspond to colors. I'm using form request validation and I have models with `belongsToMany` relationships set up for sizes and colors. When I do `Paper:create` I want to send an error if a color and size are a mismatch based on that pivot table. Is there a built-in "Laravel way" of achieving this or should I just loop through the pivot table when color and size are set?

Comment: You might be able to use the "exists" rule in Validation.  http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-exists.  However, I'd simply create a function that simply queries the pivot table and checks to see if the combination is valid.

Comment: Also you could create a after validation hook to check for conditions after you check your request. Check http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#other-validation-approaches : After Validation Hook. Might Help.

Answer (score 0):

The most "Laravely" way that I can think of, is using the form request class like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class PaperFormRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        // rules here
    }

    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();

        $validator->after(function() use ($validator) {


            // logic for detecting mismatches goes here


            // To add validation-errors, simply do:
            $validator->errors()->add(
                'colorMistmatch',
                'This color does not go with this paper'
            );

            return $validator;
        }
    }
}
```

Once errors have been added to the validator-instance, you can display them in your blade-views by doing this:

```
@if ($errors->has('colorMistmach'))
   {{ $errors->first('colorMistmach') }}
@endif
```